# Infinite Scroll loads pages only when scrolling up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [infinite scroll](https://infinite-scroll.com/). I'm trying to disable the feed like so:

```
$('.feed-container:visible').infiniteScroll('option', {loadOnScroll: false);
```

This works, however, let's say I've scrolled to the bottom of the feed and then re-enabled it:

```
$('.feed-container:visible').infiniteScroll('option', {loadOnScroll: true);
```

It won't recognize it's at the bottom and I'm forced to scroll up for it to recognize that it has hit the bottom of the page. Is there a way for it to recognize where it's at automatically?

Comment: You forgot `}` after `{loadOnScroll: true` & `{loadOnScroll: false`. Is it typo here only or in your code also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you were already at the bottom of the page so when you re-enable and try to scroll it won't scroll, so scroll event will not fire and so your infinite scroll will not work.

You can try work around like scrolling your screen up for 1px with `window.scrollBy(0, -1);` before you re-enable it.

```
window.scrollBy(0, -1);
$('.feed-container:visible').infiniteScroll('option', {loadOnScroll: true);
```

Comment: This works when I do it in the console, however, say if I am in the middle of the feed and then do display none on this feed and then do `loadOnScroll: false` and then I re-enable this feed and begin to scroll...it still won't load when I go to the bottom until I scroll up

Comment: It will be helpful if you could create fiddle for this. So others can try.

Comment: I created another question regarding my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62725384/infinite-scroll-doesnt-work-with-2-feeds